# How to check whether the dropdown values are editable-Selenium webdriver-Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

In my application,need to check whether dropdown values are editable or not using selenium webdriver Java.Can someone help me is there any possible solution to acheive that.

I tried below mentioned code with sendkeys function.But could not assign void to boolean.

```
boolean searchIconEnabled = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).isEnabled();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well you want to check that element with id=gbqfb has just attribute "disabled". You can create your own method that check if element has this attribute and return boolean.

Here is something that can help you:
[How can I verify an attribute is present in an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645013/how-can-i-verify-an-attribute-is-present-in-an-element)

Comment: I got ur point..thanks...you have any sample piece of code to check the disabled attribute

Comment: You can check link that I added to my answer. findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).getAttribute("disabled")  and if this exist just return false and else return true

Comment: I tried below mentioned code,its working fine for single value 
 driver.findElement(By.id("button")).getAttr‌​ibute("disabled") == "disabled"   but need to check for set of values

Comment: When getAttribute returns null it means that "disabled" doesn't exist. So do it : if(getAttribute("disabled")==null) return false; else return true;

Comment: Thanks!! will try this

Comment: If you want to check for set of values just check that in loop or give more details