# How to assert the text box is enabled or disabled

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, isenabled

i would like to assert whether a particular text box is disabled or enabled. below is the `HTML` for it. the difference between the disabled and enabled text box is only By `disabled` Attribute towards the end.

```
disabled text box HTML:
     <input controlid="txtIPAddress" class="textfield form-control servicefield invItem_dynamic_validation valid" id="OrderProperties_4__Value" isdisabled="true" name="OrderProperties[4].Value" style="display:" type="text" value="" disabled="">

enagled text box HTML- 
<input controlid="txtIPAddress" class="textfield form-control servicefield invItem_dynamic_validation valid" id="OrderProperties_4__Value" isdisabled="true" name="OrderProperties[4].Value" style="display:" type="text" value="">
```

I tried `element.isEnabled()` and `element.isEnabled()` methods to no avail.
any help much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify an attribute is present in an element using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645013/how-to-verify-an-attribute-is-present-in-an-element-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Hi Andersson! I have checked that link earlier. However in my case i cannot go by value of attribute as both cases the value would return null

Comment: Please check the `disabled` property, e.g. `element.disabled === true` or `element.disabled === false`

Comment: Hi Sergii! Thanks a lot for the reply . I shall check that and let you know . I didn’t know there is .disabled method as well.

Comment: Hi Sergii, i couldn't find `.disabled` method from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### isEnabled()

As per the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled--) **`isEnabled()`** method is defined as:

```
boolean isEnabled()

Description: 
    Is the element currently enabled or not? This will generally return true for everything but disabled input elements.

Returns:
    True if the element is enabled, false otherwise.
```

So your code trial as **`element.isEnabled()`** was perfect to retrieve the status whether the element was **enabled** or not provided the *element* uniquely identified the *node* which you have provided within the question.

### Alternative

As an alternative you can try to validate if the elelemt is present without the *attribute* **disabled** using the following solution:

```
try {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='textfield form-control servicefield invItem_dynamic_validation valid' and not(disabled)][@controlid='txtIPAddress']"));
    System.out.println("Element is enabled");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("Element is not enabled");
}
```

Comment: @Raj Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

To Assert Text box editable, we can use `isEnabled()` function.
See below sample,

```
boolean anytextfield = driver.findElement(By.xpath("respectivexpath")).isEnabled();
Assert.assertEquals(anytextfield,true);
```